# Excel VBA: How can I find this symbol in a string: ☒

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, special-characters

I have the following symbol in a Word document: ☒

It comes in two forms:

1. Checked: ☒
2. Not checked: ☐

I bring it back to Excel as part of a string and would like to find it within the string and identify whether it is checked or not.

It's probably identifiable as a character (ASCII, Unicode, etc.).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That's `U+2612 BALLOT BOX WITH X`.

Comment: https://unicodelookup.com/#☒/1 is decimal 9746 - in VBA `if char = chrw$(9746) ...`  (gonna have to copy paste that url)

Comment: You probably don't need to locate the exact character location, you can just test to see if that char is in the string: `If Instr(mystring, ChrW(9746)) Then` or check for the empty ballot: `If Instr(mystring, ChrW(9744)) Then`..

Comment: i copied the two symbols into word .... the font is _Segoe UI Symbol_  .............. the two characters are unicode ☐ 2610 and ☒ 2612   (hexadecimal)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I got just what I needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Function IsChecked(ByVal sInput As String) As Boolean
    IsChecked = InStr(sInput, ChrW(9746)) > 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!